# WebService PHP WSDL XML

Tags: php, xml, web-service, soap, wsdl

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP onde gerencio os meus processos judiciais.
Gostaria de receber os andamentos dos processos de forma automática, então vi que existe um WebService para facilitar essa funcionalidade.
Mas não sei absolutamente nada de WebService.
Consigo fazer a Consulta do WebService pelo SoapUI mas não sei como fazer isso pelo PHP.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Tentei fazer com o Nusoap mas já vi em outros lugares que ele não é mais recomendável.
Esse é o endereço do WSDL disponibilizado: https://pje.tjba.jus.br/pje-web/intercomunicacao?wsdl
Tentei alguma coisa com o SoapClient mas também não consegui.
Vou enviar o trecho do código:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://pje.tjba.jus.br/pje-web/intercomunicacao?wsdl', array("trace" => 1,"exceptions"=>0));


$function = 'consultarProcesso';


$arguments= array('consultarProcesso' => array(
                    'idConsultante'   => $idConsultante,
                    'senhaConsultante'      => $senhaConsultante,
                    'numeroProcesso'        => $numeroProcesso
            ));

$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments);


echo 'Response: ';
print_r($result);

//O código abaixo é para exibir o XML enviado
echo "<br><br>REQUEST<br><br>:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()). "\n";
```

Abaixo o que recebo no navegador

```
Response: SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => looks like we got no XML document [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => C:\Users\Fernando Issler\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\nusoap\index.php [line:protected] => 14 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\Users\Fernando Issler\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\nusoap\index.php [line] => 14 [function] => __soapCall [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => consultarProcesso [1] => Array ( [tipoConsultarProcesso] => Array ( [idConsultante] => 02482451558 [senhaConsultante] => Fis2047a [numeroProcesso] => 8000597-16.2019.8.05.0141 ) ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => looks like we got no XML document [faultcode] => Client [faultcodens] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ ) 

REQUEST

: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cnj.jus.br/tipos-servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.cnj.jus.br/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:consultarProcesso><ns1:idConsultante>02482451558</ns1:idConsultante><ns1:senhaConsultante>Fis2047a</ns1:senhaConsultante><ns1:numeroProcesso>8000597-16.2019.8.05.0141</ns1:numeroProcesso></ns2:consultarProcesso></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Estranhamento notei que tem dois pontos (:) antes do XML. Não sei se isso tem alguma coisa a ver.

Desde já obrigado.